# Generate MD5sum for all files in a directory, and get their matches in another directory

Tags: linux, bash, md5sum

I have 2 directories. `livedir` contains 2000 fmx files and `testdir` contains 6000 fmbs with timestamps attached. I compiled all fmb in `testdir` to fmx to match them with fmx in `livedir`.

I have created the following script to get the MD5SUM of all files in `livedir` and search if they exist in `testdir`:

```
testdir='/home/oracle/ideatest/test/'
livedir='/home/oracle/ideatest/live/'
cd /home/oracle/ideatest/live/

for f in *; do
    livefile=$(md5sum "$f" | cut -d" " -f1)
    sourcefile=$(md5sum "$testdir""$f" | cut -d" " -f1)
    if [[ -f $f ]] && [ $livefile == $sourcefile ]; then
        echo "$f" "OK-----------------------------"
        echo "$sourcefilename"
        cp /home/oracle/bankplus/ideatest/test/$f  /home/oracle/bankplus/ideatest/live2/$f
        #el moshkla f 2sm el file 3ayzo mn 3'er hash
    else
        echo "$f" "MODIFIED"
    fi
done
```

The script works only when a file with the same name exist in the 2 directories. It's because I loop using the same name `$f`:

```
sourcefile=$(md5sum "$testdir""$f" | cut -d" " -f1)
```

As a result `cp` only copies one file although I have multiple files with the same hash value in `testdir`.

Comment: I'm confused about the larger goal, but it sounds like you need to create a temporary file listing the MD5s of all files in one directory (e.g. `md5sum "$somedir"/* >"$tmpfile"`), then for each file in the other dir, scan that temp file for matching hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your bash verion is 4.2 or later, how about making use of an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash

testdir="/home/oracle/ideatest/test"
livedir="/home/oracle/ideatest/live"

declare -A hash

# 1st step: create a hash table of md5sum in $testdir
for f in $(find "$testdir" -type f); do
    md5sum=$(md5sum "$f" | cut -d" " -f1)
    hash[$md5sum]=${f##*/}  # holds md5sum as a key and filename as a value
done

# 2nd step: loop over files in $livedir and test if md5sum value of a file
# exists in $testdir
for f in $(find "$livedir" -type f); do
    basename=${f##*/}
    md5sum=$(md5sum "$f" | cut -d" " -f1)
    if [[ -n "${hash[$md5sum]}" ]]; then
        echo "$basename" "OK-----------------------------"
        echo "${hash[$md5sum]}"
        cp "/home/oracle/bankplus/ideatest/test/$basename" "/home/oracle/bankplus/ideatest/live2/$basename"
    else
        echo "$basename" "MODIFIED"
    fi
done
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you it surely works but i have manged to get to work i hwill post the answer below

Answer (score 0):

i got it working by using

```
testdir='/home/oracle/ideatest/test/'
livedir='/home/oracle/ideatest/live/'
cd /home/oracle/bankplus/ideatest/live/
        for f in *;
                 do
                        livefile=$(md5sum "$f" | cut -d" " -f1)
        for l in "$testdir"*
                 do
                        sourcefile=$(md5sum "$l" | cut -d" " -f1)
         done
                        [[ -f $f ]] && if [ $livefile == $sourcefile ]
                 then
                         echo "$f" "Found a HASH Match Copied to live2-";
                         cp $l  /home/oracle/ideatest/live2/
                 else
                         echo "$f" "MODIFIED";
                         fi;
         done
```